# EF Code-First Design: Common Collection Type on different parent types/tables

Tags: entity-framework

I need help with a design question using Entity Framework 6.1.3 from a Code-First perspective.

We have tables called "Businesses", "People", and "PhoneNumbers".  A business can have one-to-many phone numbers and person can have one-to-many phone numbers.  I'm struggling to determine the best way to implement this.  The following solutions have been explored but neither strikes me as being the "obvious" solution.  Can you please offer advice?

1. Use a common Phone table to hold numbers for the Business and People.

   In this solution, the Phone table would have RI to the People table and to the Business table.  The ID fields would be nullable so that when it is a business phone, the participant ID would be null and vice-versa:

   ```
   public Nullable<int> ParticipantID { get; set; }
   public Participant Participant { get; set; }

   public Nullable<int> BusinessID { get; set; }
   public Business Business { get; set; }
   ```
2. Create separate tables for the Business (BusinessPhone) and Person (PersonPhone) phone numbers.  Both phone tables could inherit from the original phone table but each would have separate RI statements to the corresponding Business or Person.  This way, neither table would need a nullable key.

For example, the PersonPhone table would look something like:

```
public class PersonPhone : Phone
{
    public int ParticipantID{ get; set; }
    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
}
```

Are either of these solutions best practice?  Is there a better solution?  What do you recommend?

Comment: Is a Participant actually a Person?

Comment: Yes, Participant and Person are synonymous.

Comment: Will you ever have a PhoneNumber that belongs to both a business and a person, or do you care to track that? Is there really a requirement for navigability from PhoneNumber back to owner?  Should a PhoneNumber exist without an owner, or are they composite within the owner?

Comment: Will you ever have a PhoneNumber that belongs to both a business and a person, or do you care to track that?  Yes, this is a possibility and I care about it.  Is there really a requirement for navigability from PhoneNumber back to the owner?  All the videos on Pluralsight I've seen suggest that the navigation property always be added.  Even if it isn't used for navigation, it is useful for filtering and sorting purposes when writing queries.  A phone number should always have an owner.  Thanks!

Comment: Just saw this.  If a PhoneNumber belongs to both a Person and a Business, how will that be expressed in your model?  This may moot my answer entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that the best option is to use separate tables for this.  Use a common ABC called `PhoneNumber`, and derive subclasses for each collection parent type, each mapped to their own table (TPC strategy). Or, map the ABC to a common table for the common fields, and referenced tables for the references to Person or Business (TPT strategy).

Coming from an object-oriented background where we often optimize for code-reuse; with inheritance being a strategy for reusing code; and with TPH being the default mapping of inheritance structures in EF; it *feels* right to have these both in a single table.  But looking from the perspective of a DBA, mashing these two concerns together is an abuse of the data structures in the database.  Call it "schema-smell".  It might work, but you are giving up a lot of what the database can do for you.  You're painting yourself into a corner for no good reason.

There are three inheritance strategies; this EF tutorial site [has a good rundown](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx). The single-table is TPH.  Usually I will use this even though it violates 3rd normal form, because it is simple and performant.  In the case where types differ by the other types they reference, though, the denormalization compromises offer diminishing returns.

The main problem as I see it: With one table, you have to figure out a way to mash separate FKs in.  With one column and a discriminator (which may not even be legal with EF) you lose the ability to do DRI and cascading deletes.  With two columns, you'll have to monitor that one and only one is non-null at any given time.  With either solution, you'll be giving up storage space.  If the two objects ever diverge--say, you have to add an `EmployeeName` to `BusinessPhone`--the problem will only be exacerbated.

So, in this case I would recommend either the table-per-type or table-per-concrete-type strategy over table-per-hierarchy.

The only remaining note is that all three involve compromises.  I won't get into all the trade-offs (you should be able to find many discussions of these).  There may still be cases where TPH makes the most sense because of a use-case that must perform very well.

Comment: Great explanation, this does seem like the cleaner solution considering both the relational and OO sides. PS - Surely "...as Codd and Microsoft intended" ? ;)

Comment: Hi Mark, You certainly explained the problem better than I did. Thank you.  What do you think of the idea of having the following tables - Business, Participant, PhoneNumber, Business_PhoneNumber, and Participant_PhoneNumber. The *_PhoneNumber tables would have a type so that Every Business and Person could have multiple phone types (cell, work, home, etc...). This solution would make the RI clear because the RI would be placed on the associative tables.  This solution would also allow for future expansion (EmployeeName to Business_PhoneNumber).  Every phone number would only be stored once.

Comment: @Dave, That would work as well; it is known as a table-per-type inheritance mapping (TPT).  What I proposed is table-per-concrete-class mapping (TPC). I'll edit to note both alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go at it is to have a table named 'PhoneNumber'. Both Business and People can have a list of PhoneNumbers.

Ofcourse this is only true if the PhoneNumber is equal for both Business and People. If you would like to add extra properties to a PhoneNumber for People, I would suggest going with your second option.

Comment: Thank you.  In my case, Phone Number is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single table for phone numbers seems like the better option. Could you use some sort of discriminator on your PhoneNumbers entity to avoid having to have two nullable columns?

So you'd have a PhoneNumber class, and an enumerable representing the phone number type. Then your Businesses and People each have a list of PhoneNumber as you've mentioned. Example -

```
public class PhoneNumber
{   
    public int PhoneNumberId { get; set; }      
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }        
    public PhoneNumberType PhoneNumberType { get; set; }
    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
}

public enum PhoneNumberType
{
    Person,
    Business
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160269/entity-framework-code-first-shared-1-to-many-entity?rq=1) is to a very similar question and seems like an even better option if you want to give it a look.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent documentation and suggestions.  This, and the similar question, are approaches I had not considered.

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but will require "overloading" a foreign key column which (a) EF may not even allow, and (b) any DBA will throw a fit about, because it violates normal forms and makes DRI with the table impossible.